# How to clear multidimensional array of Word in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, multidimensional-array

I am using Delphi 7 and I try to clear (i.e fill with zeros) the array of declaration:

```
const CONST_MAX_INDEX_AllColumnsSeparators = 3658;
type TAllColumnsSeparators = array[0..CONST_MAX_INDEX_AllColumnsSeparators] of Word;
type ColSeparators = Array[0..11] of TAllColumnsSeparators; // count of columns
   
var All_separators: ColSeparators;
```

Acoording this page, there should be function System.Array.Clear  - but seems like this could be for newer IDE than Delphi v. 7.

```
System.Array.Clear(All_separators, 0, CONST_MAX_INDEX_AllColumnsSeparators+1);
```

I got error undefined identifier Array.

I thought, I could to do this in a loop reseting manually, but I guess that would be slow performance job.

Notice: I have 63 files processed in a loop which needs to reset this array in every cycle, so this command will be nested in a loop. So I guess there should be some smart way to do it fast and easy without another control loop.

Comment: When you say "clear", do you mean "fill with zeros"?

Comment: Exactly. To fill with zeros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that, given your

```pascal
const
  CONST_MAX_INDEX_AllColumnsSeparators = 3658;

type
  TAllColumnsSeparators = array[0..CONST_MAX_INDEX_AllColumnsSeparators] of Word;
  TColSeparators = array[0..11] of TAllColumnsSeparators;
```

both types are [static arrays](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Static_Arrays) which are *value* types. Hence, the outermost array type is also a value type containing nothing but a sequence of `Word`s. Hence, to fill such a variable with zeros (zero `Word`s), you only need to fill its memory with zeros (zero `Byte`s):

```pascal
var
  AllSeparators: TColSeparators;
begin
  FillChar(AllSeparators, SizeOf(AllSeparators), 0);
```

Comment: And if you want to Fill only certain column with zeroes you can call `FillChar(AllSeparators[ColNum], SizeOf(AllSeparators[ColNum]), 0);` where `ColNum` is the number of the specific column that you want to fill with Zeroes. Just make sure that `ColNum` is never larger than the number of actual columns in your multidimensional array or you will end up Zeroing memory that belongs to something else since `FillChar` function doesn't preform any range checking.

Comment: That definition could be `array[0.. 11, 0.. CONST_MAX_INDEX_AllColumnsSeparators]` right away (which also helps understanding it is in fact only one long line of `Word`s).

Comment: I prefer using ``ZeroMemory`` rather than ``FillChar``.

Comment: `FillChar` is a standard Pascal procedure while `ZeroMemory` is Windows API function, so I tend to use `FillChar` in pure Delphi scenarios and `ZeroMemory` when I work with the Windows API. A clear benefit of `ZeroMemory`, of course, is that it is more semantic or specific (special case of char = 0). Another difference is that `FillChar` takes a variable while `ZeroMemory` takes a pointer, so if you have a variable, then `FillChar` is slightly neater (and more type safe). On the other hand, `ZeroMemory` is slightly more powerful but also more dangerous.